# Find the distance between two sets in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the disjoint closed sets in $\Bbb R^2$ given by

$A=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : y=0 \}$ and $B=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 :xy=1\}$.

What is the distance between them?

Here, $A$ is the $x$ axis and $B$ is a hyperbola with two asymptotes. How to find the distance between them?

But, the answer is given as $0.$

Any help?

Comment: The hyperbola and $x$-axis get very close as $x$ gets large ...

Comment: What is the definition of asymptote and that of distance between sets? The answer will follow from these

Comment: @mbe: the definition is $d(A,B)=inf \{ d(a,b): a \in A , b \in B\}$. How the result follows from this? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Dim We have that B is a set with asymptote A. Hence this infimum is taken over a set with arbitrarily small (yet positive) numbers.

Comment: Observe that for any $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, we have $d(A,B)\leq d(a,b)$.  If we want to show that $d(A,B)=0$, just show that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $d(a,b)<\varepsilon$. From this the result will follow.

Comment: For all $x>0,$ $d(A,B) \le d((x,0),(x,1/x)) = 1/x \to 0$ as $x\to \infty.$

Comment: "If you wish to discourse with me you must define your terms."--- Voltaire.... You cannot measure   the distance from $A$ to $B$ until you define it. If you define it as $\inf \{d(p,q):p\in A\land q\in B\}$ then it is zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that $\inf\limits_{a \in A, b \in B}|a-b| = 0$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$; let $a:= \left(\frac2\varepsilon,0\right)$; let $b:= \left(\frac2\varepsilon,\frac{\varepsilon}2\right)$. Then $a \in A$ and $b \in B$; and $0 < |a-b| = \frac{\varepsilon}2 < \varepsilon$. So, the distance between $A$ and $B$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly trivial to prove that the distance of these two sets is zero, but it is interesting to note that they can still be separated by disjoint open sets in $\Bbb R^2$ under the standard metric.

So it need not be necessary that the distance of two closed sets to be non-zero to get it separated by disjoint open ball. This might seem a little counter-intuitive.

In fact, all metric spaces are normal!

Comment: And hence completely regular . In fact every completely regular space has a pseudo metric.

Comment: Tui keti bhai!!